# bitwise XOR a string in Bash

Tags: perl, bash, scripting, shell

I am trying to accomplish a work in Bash scripting. I have a string which i want to XOR with my key.

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin export PATH

teststring="abcdefghijklmnopqr"
```

Now how do i XOR the value of teststring and store it in a variable using bash?

Any help will be appreciated.

Basically i am trying to duplicate the result of follwing VB Script:

```
Function XOREncryption(CodeKey, DataIn)

Dim lonDataPtr
Dim strDataOut
Dim temp
Dim tempstring
Dim intXOrValue1
Dim intXOrValue2


For lonDataPtr = 1 To Len(DataIn) Step 1
    'The first value to be XOr-ed comes from the data to be encrypted
    intXOrValue1 = Asc(Mid(DataIn, lonDataPtr, 1))
    'The second value comes from the code key
    intXOrValue2 = Asc(Mid(CodeKey, ((lonDataPtr Mod Len(CodeKey)) + 1), 1))

    temp = (intXOrValue1 Xor intXOrValue2)
    tempstring = Hex(temp)
    If Len(tempstring) = 1 Then tempstring = "0" & tempstring

    strDataOut = strDataOut + tempstring
Next
XOREncryption = strDataOut
End Function
```

Comment: Wouldn't it just be `teststring="abcdefghijklmnopqr" ^ key`?

Comment: maybe if there is some way to pass the value of teststring in perl from bash script and XOR it there.

Comment: It sounds like your trying to do some sort of password obfuscation or encryption in bash.  Perl or python would probably be a better choice of language.

Comment: it seems it can't be done staying all into bash.. so maybe you should stick to perl, or use something more lightweight than an interpreter of a language; e.g. od and sed could be used e.g.: `echo $(( $(echo -n "c" |od -td1 |sed -e 's/^[0-9]\+ *//g;') ^ 1 ))`; put your char instead of "c"... better if you make this as a function; then you can split char by char the string and apply the xor (maybe xorring char by char was not what you wanted...; if you need xorring two same-length strings, you can split both and "build" the result; otherwise string ^ integer ... what do you mean?

Comment: It can all be done in BASH. See my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

With the help of [these hints](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/071) i wrote this quickly script to complete Pedro's answer:

```
#!/bin/bash

function ascii2dec
{
  RES=""
  for i in `echo $1 | sed "s/./& /g"`
  do 
    RES="$RES `printf \"%d\" \"'$i'\"`"
  done 
  echo $RES
}

function dec2ascii
{
  RES=""
  for i in $*
  do 
    RES="$RES`printf \\\\$(printf '%03o' $i)`"
  done 
  echo $RES
}

function xor
{
  KEY=$1
  shift
  RES=""
  for i in $*
  do
    RES="$RES $(($i ^$KEY))"
  done

  echo $RES
}


KEY=127
TESTSTRING="abcdefghijklmnopqr"

echo "Original String: $TESTSTRING"
STR_DATA=`ascii2dec "$TESTSTRING"`
echo "Original String Data: $STR_DATA"
XORED_DATA=`xor $KEY $STR_DATA`
echo "XOR-ed Data: $XORED_DATA"
RESTORED_DATA=`xor $KEY $XORED_DATA`
echo "Restored Data: $RESTORED_DATA"
RESTORED_STR=`dec2ascii $RESTORED_DATA`
echo "Restored String: $RESTORED_STR"
```

Result:

```
iMac:Desktop fer$ bash test.sh
Original String: abcdefghijklmnopqr
Original String Data: 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 
XOR-ed Data: 30 29 28 27 26 25 24 23 22 21 20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13
Restored Data: 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 
Restored String: abcdefghijklmnopqr
```

Comment: This is XORing with a key of only one byte.

Comment: This can only XOR ASCII strings. Does not work with unicode.

Comment: Backticks are depreciated. Please replace them with command substitution constructs `$()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you decide to go for Perl one-liner, here is what I came up with

```
perl -e '@a=split("", $ARGV[0]); @b=split("", $ARGV[1]); print unpack "H2", chr(ord(shift @a)^ord(shift @b)) while @a; print "\n"' aab aaa
```

zip function in Perl 6 would do a better job...

Answer (score 1):

yet another answer

```
function xenc {
  local data=$1 key=$2
  local _data _key ndata nkey count i _res
  _data=($(eval printf "'%d '" $(printf "%s" "$data" | sed -e '$!N;${s/./"'"'"'&" /g;s/""/\\&/g}')))
  _key=($(eval printf "'%d '" $(printf "%s" "$key" | sed '$!N;${s/./"'"'"'&" /g;s/""/\\&/g}')))
  ndata=${#_data[@]} nkey=${#_key[@]}
  (( count = ndata < nkey ? nkey : ndata ))
  for ((i = 0; i < count; i++)); do
    (( _res[i] = ${_data[i]:-0} ^ ${_key[i%nkey]:-0} ))
  done
  printf "\\\\\\%o" "${_res[@]}"  | xargs printf
}
res=$(xenc abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz FLqFb8LU0TY)
xenc "$res" FLqFb8LU0TY
```

Comment: You can use a loop `data=abcdef; for ((i=0;i<${#data};i++)); do printf '%d ' "'${data:i:1}"; done` to avoid the complex construct using  eval and calling an external command `sed`.

Comment: As is very possible to emit control characters with the xor, it is reasonable to present the encoded result as hex digits (as the question request).

Comment: @JosEduSol In fact, this is a reasonable solution to the question asked: A bash script to xor two strings (as ascii values). to that effect, change  `printf "\\\\\\%o" "${_res[@]}"  | xargs printf` to the simpler `printf '%02x' "${_res[@]}"`

Answer (score 0):

Bitwise exclusive-OR in BASH requires both operands to be numeric. Since there's no built-in way of getting the ordinal (ASCII) value of a character in bash, you'll need to use, say, Perl, to get that value.

**Edit**: as noted below, `ord` works on the first character of a string only.

```
let a=`perl -e 'print ord $_ for split //, $ARGV[0]' string`^123; echo $a
```

Of course, once you're in Perl, you might as well do it all there:

```
let a=`perl -e '$ordinal .= ord $_ for split //, $ARGV[0]; print $ordinal ^ $ARGV[1]' string 123`
```

**Edit**: it turns out you can grab the ordinal value of a string in BASH using `printf`. Simply prefix the string with `'`.

```
printf "%d" "'string"
```

So, in BASH only:

```
let a=$(printf "%d" "'string")^123; echo $a
```

Comment: i have something like this in bash but its showing 0 as output...

username=`whoami`
test=`perl -e 'print ord $strUrl ^ key'`
echo ${test}

am i making any mistake?

Comment: You need to wrap the `perl` command in either backticks or $(). Also, `$strUrl` is undefined, and `key` is a bareword.

Comment: Is this the proper way of doing it? i am getting a two digit number as output but i was expecting a long number.



key=secret
strUrl=cdcdcdc
strUrl=$(($(printf "%d" "'strUrl")^$(printf "%d" "'key")));echo $strUrl

Comment: `ord` operates on a single character, so `ord $ARGV[0]` returns the ordinal value of the *first character* of `$ARGV[0]`

Comment: You're getting the result in decimal format. Convert it to binary with `unpack("N", pack("B32", substr("0" x 32 . $decimal, -32)))`

Comment: @Pedro, should the unpack be wrapped in ticks?

Comment: strUrl=unpack("N", pack("B32", substr("0" x 32 . $strUrl, -32)))

This line gives me "Syntax error: "(" unexpected" message

Comment: ricky, the unpack is within perl. In any case, just go with the all-BASH version

Comment: @pedro, this gives me a blank output...

Did you also notice the VBscript version of the function which i am trying to match my output to?

    strUrl=$(($(printf "%d" "'strUrl")^$(printf "%d" "'key")));
    strUrl=`perl -le 'unpack("N", pack("B32", substr("0" x 32 . $strUrl, -32)))'`

Any ideas?

Comment: `$strUrl` in the perl portion is undefined. Passed it as an argument, like so: `strUrl=perl -le 'unpack("N", pack("B32", substr("0" x 32 . $ARGV[0], -32)))' $strUrl`

Answer (score 0):

The most similar transformation of only the function to bash would be:
(# means comment):

```sh
# Function XOREncryption(CodeKey, DataIn)
XOREncryption(){
    local CodeKey=$1
    local DataIn=$2
    # Dim lonDataPtr strDataOut temp tempstring intXOrValue1 intXOrValue2
    local lonDataPtr strDataOut temp tempstring intXOrValue1 intXOrValue2

    # For lonDataPtr = 1 To Len(DataIn) Step 1
    for (( lonDataPtr=0; lonDataPtr < ${#DataIn}; lonDataPtr++ )); do
        #The first value to be XOr-ed comes from the data to be encrypted
    # intXOrValue1 = Asc(Mid(DataIn, lonDataPtr, 1))
    intXOrValue1=$( toAsc "${DataIn:$lonDataPtr:1}" )
    echo "val1=$intXOrValue1 and=<${DataIn:$lonDataPtr:1}> and $(toAsc "${DataIn:$lonDataPtr:1}")"
        #The second value comes from the code key
    echo "Ptr=$lonDataPtr Mod=<$(( lonDataPtr % ${#CodeKey} ))>"
    # intXOrValue2 = Asc(Mid(CodeKey, ((lonDataPtr Mod Len(CodeKey)) + 1), 1))
    intXOrValue2=$( toAsc "${CodeKey:$(( lonDataPtr % ${#CodeKey} )):1}" )
    echo "val1=$intXOrValue1 val2=<${CodeKey:$(( lonDataPtr % ${#CodeKey} )):1}> and |$intXOrValue2|"
    # temp = (intXOrValue1 Xor intXOrValue2)
    temp=$(( intXOrValue1 ^ intXOrValue2 ))
    echo "temp=$temp"
        # tempstring = Hex(temp)
    tempstring=$(printf '%02x' "$temp")
    echo "tempstring=$tempstring"
    # strDataOut = strDataOut + tempstring
        strDataOut+=$tempstring
    echo
    # Next
    done
    # XOREncryption = strDataOut
    printf '%s\n' "$strDataOut"
# End Function
}
```

Removing the comments, and cleaning the code:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

Asc() { printf '%d' "'$1"; }

XOREncryption(){
    local key=$1 DataIn=$2
    local ptr DataOut val1 val2

    for (( ptr=0; ptr < ${#DataIn}; ptr++ )); do
        val1=$( Asc "${DataIn:$ptr:1}" )
        val2=$( Asc "${key:$(( ptr % ${#key} )):1}" )
        DataOut+=$(printf '%02x' "$(( val1 ^ val2 ))")
    done
    printf '%s\n' "$DataOut"
}

CodeKey="$1"
teststring="$2"
XOREncryption "$CodeKey" "$teststring"
```

---

Running it:

```
$ ./script.sh "123456789" "abcdefghijklmnopqr"
5050505050505050505b595f595b5947494b
```

Answer (score -1):

woks in busybox(the paste could not receive two streams), also made the key to repeat

```
#!/bin/sh
numitems() { i=0;while read ITEM; do i=$(( $i + 1 )) ; done; echo $i; }
starmap() { while read ITEM; do $1 $ITEM; done; }
ord() { printf '%d\n' "'$1"; }
chr() { printf \\$(printf '%03o' $1); }
split_chars() { echo -n "$1" | sed 's/./&\n/g'; }
xor() { echo $(($1 ^ $2)); }
map_ord() { split_chars "$1" | starmap ord; }
encrypt()
{
KEY=$1;STR=$2;
while [ ${#KEY} -lt ${#STR} ]; do KEY="$KEY$KEY"; done; #make key longer then str
[ -e /tmp/paste_col1 ] && rm -rf /tmp/paste_col1
[ -e /tmp/paste_col1t ] && rm -rf /tmp/paste_col1t
[ -e /tmp/paste_col2 ] && rm -rf /tmp/paste_col2
map_ord "$KEY">/tmp/paste_col1t
map_ord "$STR">/tmp/paste_col2
head -n `wc -l /tmp/paste_col2 |sed -r 's|^([0-9]+)\s.*|\1|'` /tmp/paste_col1t>/tmp/paste_col1 #trim lines
[ -e /tmp/paste_col1t ] && rm -rf /tmp/paste_col1t
paste /tmp/paste_col1 /tmp/paste_col2 | starmap xor | starmap chr
[ -e /tmp/paste_col1 ] && rm -rf /tmp/paste_col1
[ -e /tmp/paste_col2 ] && rm -rf /tmp/paste_col2
echo
}
KEY="12345678"
TESTSTRING="abcdefghasdfasdfasfdas"
encrypt "$KEY" "$TESTSTRING"
ENC="`encrypt \"$KEY\" \"$TESTSTRING\"`"
encrypt "$KEY" "$ENC" # we should get $TESTSTRING again
```

Comment: The output could be any byte value, `chr` that produce control characters is not a good idea. That's why the code in the question use `Hex` for the output.